# Applying 2D Gabor Wavelet on Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

EDIT: This is the code I am using that generates an edge detected looking image:

```
cookiesImage = rgb2gray(imread('Cookies.png'));
width = 45;
height = 45;
KMAX = pi / 2;
f = sqrt(2);
delta = pi / 3;

output = zeros(size(cookiesImage, 1), size(cookiesImage, 2), 8);


for i = 0 : 7
wavelets = GaborWavelet(width, height, KMAX, f, i, 2, delta);
figure(1);
subplot(1, 8, i + 1), imshow(real(wavelets), []);
output(:, :, i + 1) = imfilter(cookiesImage, wavelets, 'symmetric');
end

display = sum(abs(output).^2, 3).^0.5;
display = display./max(display(:));
figure(2); imshow(display);


 function GWKernel = GaborWavelet (width, height, KMAX, f, u , v,  delta)
delta2 = delta * delta;
kv = KMAX / (f^v);
thetaU = (u * pi) / 8;
kuv = kv * exp (1i * thetaU);
kuv2 = abs(kuv)^2;

GWKernel = zeros (height, width);
for y =  -height/ 2 + 1 : height / 2
    for x = -width / 2 + 1 : width / 2
        GWKernel(y + height / 2, x + width / 2) = (kuv2 / delta2) * exp(-0.5 * kuv2 * (x * x + y * y) / delta2) * (exp(1i * (real(kuv) * y + imag (kuv) * x )) - exp (-0.5 * delta2));
    end
end
```

This is the function that I am using for the Wavelets and this is how I am trying to apply them but all I am getting is an edge detected looking image, rather than one as in [this link](http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/ToolGaborFilterExample.png).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Getting this error now. Error using * Inner matrix dimensions must agree. Will this work for grayscale?

Comment: Is the expected image suppose to look like an edge detection image?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out @CrisLuengo. I posted an updated code sample of what I am working with and my problem. If you could offer assistance, I would very much appreciate it. I am looking more for the image you posted rather than an edge detected looking one.

Comment: I've edited the link from my comment into the question, so it stays self-contained.

Comment: Thank you. I was navigating the FEX and was confused as to which is the best approach to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code, I see the following wavelets being generated:

[image]

These look a lot like rotated second derivatives. This is only the real (even) component of the Gabor filter kernels. The imaginary (odd) counterparts look like first derivatives.

This is why you feel like your result is like an edge-detected image. It sort of is.

Try increasing the size of the filter (not the footprint `width`x`height`, but the `delta` that determines the size of the envelope). This will make it so that you see a larger portion of the sinusoid waves that form the Gabor kernel.

Next, the result image you show is the sum of the square magnitude of the individual Gabor filters. Try displaying the real or imaginary components of one of the filter results, you'll see it looks more like you'd expect:

```
imshow(real(output(:,:,3)),[])
```

---

I'm not familiar with this parametrization of the Gabor kernel, but note that it has a Gaussian envelope. Therefore, the footprint (`width`, `height`) of the kernel can be adjusted to the size of this Gaussian (which seems to use `delta` as the sigma). I typically recommend using a kernel footprint of `2*ceil(3*sigma)+1` for the Gaussian kernel. The same applies here:

```
width = 2*ceil(3*delta)+1;
height = width;
```

This will speed up computations, as you see in the image above your kernels have lots of near-zero values in them, it is possible to crop them to a smaller size without affecting the output.

The `GaborWavelet` function can also be simplified a lot using vectorization:

```
function GWKernel = GaborWavelet (width, height, KMAX, f, u , v,  delta)
delta2 = delta * delta;
kv = KMAX / (f^v);
thetaU = (u * pi) / 8;
kuv = kv * exp (1i * thetaU);
kuv2 = abs(kuv)^2;

x = -width/2 + 1 : width/2;
[x,y] = meshgrid(x,x);
GWKernel = (kuv2 / delta2) * exp(-0.5 * kuv2 * (x .* x + y .* y) / delta2) ...
           .* (exp(1i * (real(kuv) * y + imag (kuv) * x )) - exp (-0.5 * delta2));
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Cris. Do you have a good idea as to increasing the delta? Like what is a baseline?

Comment: It's a compromise between locality in space and frequency. The larger the delta, the more precisely you are selecting a frequency band, but the larger your spatial filter will be, so your spatial precision decreases (the output is more "blurry"). What is optimal depends on the application.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!